Prometheus Alerts missing labels
I am trying to create a dashboard that shows problems/alerts with my server.
The alert triggers, but the labels remain empty.
Prometheus Alert triggering
As you can see, the {{$labels.job}} doesn't show the job. I've tried changing this to {{ $labels.instance }}, with the same result.
This is my alert_rules.yml:
groups:
  - name: high_cpu_usage
    rules:
      - alert: HighCPUUsage
        expr: avg by (job) (100 - (100 * avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle", job="node_secure"}[1m]))))
        for: 10s
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: "High CPU usage on {{ $labels.job }}"
          description: "CPU usage on {{ $labels.job }} has been above 90% for more than 1 minute."

This is my prometheus.yml:
global:
  scrape_interval:     1s
  evaluation_interval: 1s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'example'

rule_files:
   - alert_rules.yml
  # - "second_rules.yml"

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets: ['alertmanager:9093']

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'node_secure'
    scheme: https
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['mct-deco-nodeexporter.com:443']
        labels:
          job: "node_secure"
    tls_config:
      ca_file: /certificates/cert_and_key.pem
      insecure_skip_verify: true

I tried adding the labels in my job in the prometheus configuration which didn't change anything. I tried adding that specific label to my query with the same result.

avg (the internal one, without by clause) drops all labels. The outer one even though it tries to group by job, doesn't have anything to group by. Additionally, I don't see why you would need two calls for avg: just add by clause to the inner one and omit outer.

Additionally, you can run your query in the web console of Prometheus. You'll se resulting labels there, and also will have a chance to debug expression itself.
